Are the projection functions on the space of functions $\sum_j a_j e^{i \lambda_j x}$ continuous wrt the sup-norm?
In my previous question I was interested in an explicit lower bound for $ \displaystyle \sup_{x \in \mathbb R} \big |\sum_j a_j e^{i \lambda_j x}\big|$ in terms of the coefficients $a_j$. It turns out the explicit bound I guessed was dead wrong.
Now I am interested in a softer question. Consider the vector space of functions of the form  $\displaystyle\sum_{\lambda \in A} a_\lambda e^{i \lambda x}$ for finite sets $A \subset \mathbb R$ and coefficients $a_\lambda \in  \mathbb R$. Give it the sup-norm. This is always finite by the triangle inequality and so   $\displaystyle\sum_{\lambda \in A} a_\lambda e^{i \lambda x} $ has norm at most $ \sum |a_\lambda|$
For fixed $\mu \in \mathbb R$ define the projection $\pi_{\mu}$ by $\displaystyle\sum_{\lambda \in A} a_\lambda e^{i \lambda x} \mapsto a_\mu$ taking $a_\mu =0$ for $\mu \notin A$.
Are these projections continuous?

This follows from considering the uniform mean value $M(f)=\lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^Tf(x)dx$. It is obvious that for any generalized trigonometric polynomial $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{\lambda \in A} a_\lambda e^{i \lambda x}$ as above $M(f)$ exists and $M(f)=a_0$
Denoting $||f||_{\infty}=\sup_{x \in \mathbb R}|f(x)|$ it follows that if $f_n$ is a sequence of generalized trigonometric polynomials as above st  $||f_n-f||_{\infty} \to 0$ for some function $f$ then $M(f)$ exists and $M(f_n) \to M(f)$ so $M$ is continuous w.r. uniform norm.
(such limits belong to the space of almost periodic functions btw - though in general that space is defined by an almost periodicity notion and then it is part of the theory that they have a corresponding generalized Fourier series that is unique but which may not converge uniformly to it, so functions $f$ that are in the uniform closure as above are a subset of the full almost periodic space, kind of like the periodic functions that are the uniform limit of their Fourier series are a subspace of all periodic continuous functions)
In particular $a_{\lambda}=M(f(x)e^{-i\lambda x})$ gives the required continuity asked in the OP.
